# I want to control the texteditingcontroller for each of the IngredientContainers' so that i can display it on my screen

Tags: flutter, dart

[Instead all of them being Hello i want each of them to be individually typed in and different val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rCHE.png)

Here's the code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:recipe_saver/Screens/saver_recipes.dart';

class RecipeEditorScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_RecipeEditorScreenState createState() => _RecipeEditorScreenState();
}

class _RecipeEditorScreenState extends State<RecipeEditorScreen> {
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
List IngredientContainer = [];

final textFieldEdit = TextEditingController();

TextEditingController IngredientSaver = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
     children: [
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height,
        width: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.blueGrey, Colors.blueGrey[900]])),
      ),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: Platform.isIOS ? 60 : 30, horizontal: 30),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
```

saverecipes()));
},
child: Text(
"Recipe",
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.white,
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
),
),
),
GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
Navigator.push(context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
saverecipes()));
},
child: Text(
"Saver",
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.blue,
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
),
),
),
],
),
),
SizedBox(
height: 30,
),
Stack(
children: [
Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
vertical: Platform.isIOS ? 120 : 90, horizontal: 5),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
gradient: LinearGradient(
colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.blueAccent],
),
),
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
children: [
Row(
children: [
Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 5),
child: Text(
"Dish:",
style: TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
color: Colors.black,
fontSize: 35,
fontFamily: 'Overpass',
),
),
),
Expanded(
child: Padding(
padding:
EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 5, left: 10),
child: TextField(
controller: textFieldEdit,
cursorColor: Colors.black,
decoration: InputDecoration(
hintText: "Enter Dish Title",
hintStyle: TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
fontSize: 25,
color: Colors.grey,
),
enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
borderSide:
BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent),
),
focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
borderSide:
BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent),
)),
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'Overpass',
fontSize: 35,
color: Colors.black,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
),
),
),
],
),
SizedBox(
height: 50,
),
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [
Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
child: Text(
"Ingredients:",
style: TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
color: Colors.black,
fontSize: 25,
fontFamily: 'Overpass'),
),
),
IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline,
size: 30, color: Colors.black),
onPressed: () {
setState(() {
IngredientContainer.add('');
});
},
),
],
),
Expanded(
child: Container(
height: double.infinity,
width: MediaQuery
.of(context)
.size
.width,
child: ListView.builder(
itemCount: IngredientContainer.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return Container(
height: 50,
width: MediaQuery
.of(context)
.size
.width,
child: Row(
children: [
Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),
child: Text(
"Ingredient:",
style: TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
fontFamily: 'OverPass',
fontSize: 17,
),
),
),
Expanded(
child: Padding(
padding:
EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
child: TextField(
controller: IngredientSaver,
cursorColor: Colors.black,
decoration: InputDecoration(
hintText: 'Type Ingredient
Here',
hintStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize: 17,
fontFamily: 'Overpass',
fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
color: Colors.grey,
),
enabledBorder:
UnderlineInputBorder(
borderSide: BorderSide(
color: Colors.blueAccent),
),
focusedBorder:
UnderlineInputBorder(
borderSide: BorderSide(
color: Colors.blueAccent),
),
),
style: TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
fontFamily: 'Overpass',
fontSize: 17,
color: Colors.black,
),
),
),
),
GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
setState(() {

```
                      IngredientContainer.removeAt(index);
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 7),
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [Colors.blueGrey, 
               Colors.blueGrey[900]]
                        ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Enter",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontFamily: 'Overpass',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: Colors.black
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: please write code as Text ,not in image

Comment: sure thing just edited the code and wrote it as text